# Hot reload throws error when SingleTickerProviderStateMixin is used #42054

Tags: flutter, dart, animation

I implemented animation in some pages, and I have used SingleTickerProviderStateMixin, when I hot reload the screen, it throws an error as follows.

```
If a State is used for multiple AnimationController objects, or if it is passed to other objects and those objects might use it more than one time in total, then instead of mixing in a SingleTickerProviderStateMixin, use a regular TickerProviderStateMixin.

E/flutter ( 7919): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(178)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 7919): _SplashState is a SingleTickerProviderStateMixin but multiple tickers were created.
E/flutter ( 7919): A SingleTickerProviderStateMixin can only be used as a TickerProvider once. If a State is used for multiple AnimationController objects, or if it is passed to other objects and those objects might use it more than one time in total, then instead of mixing in a SingleTickerProviderStateMixin, use a regular TickerProviderStateMixin.
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I used `TickerProviderStateMixin` instead of `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin`.

I figured out that I used a sub widget that uses animation as well, so it counts as multiple `AnimationController` objects.